# Foreign Key is set to NULL in ObjectStateManager DetectChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Occasionally during a `SaveChanges()` call one of the foreign keys (`Container`) on our `Document` object is set to NULL. This happens during the `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` call inside of our `SaveChanges()` override.

Our `Document` object is defined as:

```
public class Document
{
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public int ContainerId { get; set; }

    Container _container;
    public virtual Container Container
    {
        get { return _container; }
        set
        {
            _container = value;
            ContainerId = value != null ? value.Id : 0;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

I have been unable to determine why this only happens occasionally.  If I put a breakpoint immediately before the `DetectChanges()` call both the `ContainerId` and `Container` properties are set correctly.  Immediately after they are set to 0 and NULL.

I've used DotTrace to debug inside of `DetectChanges` and I can see that the following is happening in the `ObjectStateManager`:

1. `DetectChanges()` calls `DetectChangesInNavigationProperties()`
2. `DetectChangesInNavigationProperties()` calls
3. `DetectChangesInRelationshipsOfSingleEntity()`
4. Inside of `DetectChangesInRelationshipsOfSingleEntity` the `Document.Container` relationship is added to the `TransactionManager.DeletedRelationshipsByGraph` Dictionary
5. `DetectChanges()` calls `AlignChangesInRelationships()`
6. `AlignChangesInRelationships()` calls `PerformDelete()`
7. `PerformDelete()` removes the relationship

I've been trying to debug the `DetectChangesInRelationshipsOfSingleEntity()` call without any success.  I can see the [decompiled `DetectChangesInRelationshipsOfSingleEntity` method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAk9P.png), but it won't let me break inside. Even if I could I'm not certain I'd be able to determine the cause. I've examined the `ObjectStateMangager` in depth for saves that work and saves that fail and I cannot see any differences.

During the failed saves the error message is as follows:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

Anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing this to occasionally happen in `DetectChanges`?  Obviously there a difference in the `ObjectContext` between the saves that fail and the saves that work, but so far I've failed to identify it.

Comment: The problem was due to the following:

Container also contained a List<Document>, and the new document wasn't present in that list (due to application level permissions blocking the add).  Because it was missing EntityFramework was adding it to the DeletedRelationshipsByGraph dictionary and setting it to NULL during DetectChanges().  Once it was added properly to the Conainer.Documents list everything worked correctly.